# Python2 to python3 lists and bytes vs strings

Tags: python, arrays, string, cgi

I have a list of IP addresses I telnet to and gather data from. I put this data into two variables. I then want to print the data from the variables into a HTML table. It worked in Python 2 but doesn't in Python 3. It is giving me the following error:`Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`. I see other people giving explanations to the byte code vs string code but what about lists? Please help if you can.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi, cgitb
import telnetlib
import re
import socket

user            = 'usr'
password        = 'pwd'

print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")
print ("<title>Locating IP Addresses</title>")
print ("<link href=\"/styles/main.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" >")
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")

for count in ["10.1.1.4", "10.1.1.3", "10.1.1.2"]:
    server = (count)
    try:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(server)
        tn.read_until(b"ogin")
        tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
        tn.read_until(b"assword")
        tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\r\n")
        tn.write(b"environment no more\r\n")
        tn.write(b"configure\r\n")
        tn.write(b"router\r\n")
        tn.write(b"info\r\n")
        tn.write(b"logout\r\n")
        output = (tn.read_all())
        interfaces = (re.findall(b'interface\s\"(.+)\"', output))
        ipaddr = (re.findall(b'address\s(.+)/', output))
        print ("<table>")
        print ("<tr>")
        print ("<th class=\"bld\">%s</th>" % (server))
        print ("</tr>")
        for i,j in zip(interfaces, ipaddr):
            print ("<tr>")
            print (("<td class=\"sn\">"+j+"</td>" "<td class=\"prt\">"+i+"</td>"))

        except socket.error:
            print ("communication error with " + server)

print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")
```

Comment: I may be able to help, but can you post the full error message, i.e. including line numbers? I can't see where the error is occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use bytes in a regex, the  results will also be bytes, in this case that means `interfaces` and `ipaddr` will be lists of bytes.

Later you try to concatenate these results with strings using the `+` operator, which doesn't allow to mix `bytes` and `str`.

Try this instead:

```
print("<td class=\"sn\">"+j.decode()+"</td><td class=\"prt\">"+i.decode()+"</td>")
```

Comment: You are awesome my friend.  Worked like a charm.